# How to vendor and product id on WinCE device

Tags: c++, visual-c++, smartphone, pocketpc

I am new to USB HID on winCE.  Could someone tell me how to get vendor and product onreport under windowCE environment. On window side there is function called SetupDiGetDeviceProperty, is there an equvient term on the windowCE side?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

OemInfo, from docs: "   Requests OEM-specific information. The information string can include, but is not limited to, the model name, model number, and manufacturer."

```
// Device Manufacturer 
TCHAR oemInfo[256]; 
ZeroMemory(oeminf, sizeof(oemInfo));
SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETOEMINFO, 255, &oemInfo, false );
```

OemType, from docs: "Requests a string that identifies the Windows CE–based platform type. Do not localize this string."

```
TCHAR oemType[256]; 
ZeroMemory(oemType, sizeof(oemType));
SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETPLATFORMTYPE, 255, &oemType, false );
```